# How to increase text size of option menu programmatically?

Tags: android, optionmenu

I need to increase the font size of option menu. I do search web for this but all i got is to modify android option menu's internal view(com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView ) to change text size. But i am looking for a way without modifying any kind of internal view's as it is not recommended. Can anybody please refer me a document or source code that will do my task(change android option menu item text size programmatically). Any kinds of link resource's is really appreciable.

i got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591164/how-to-change-menu-item-color-size-programmatically) type of answer that is really helpful, but all i want a simple & elegant solution.