# How to set the background color of the overflow menu

Tags: android, menu, colors, background, overflow

I am trying to set the background drawable/color of the overflow menu dynamically in code and have found answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591164/how-to-change-menu-item-color-size-programmatically) that DON'T WORK for Android 4.x. Does anyone have a solution or ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Did you even try to look this up? Googling "set android overflow menu color" gave me everything you need to know in the first few results.

Comment: none of them work. that's why i re-posted.

Comment: Tell us what you tried, then.

Comment: everything suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591164/how-to-change-menu-item-color-size-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, I found many solutions before but none of them were working for 4.4. I had to change define a custom theme and use the following in a `style` as mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20077381/1306419) answer on [How to change the background color of Action Bar's Option Menu in Android 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2) question. My sniplet below is also from there. Thanks to [@Jonik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56285/jonik). :

```
<style name="MyAppActionBarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- The beef: background color for Action Bar overflow menu -->
<style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
</style>
```

Also I remember that this somehow didn't work if instead of `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"`, I used `parent= "android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"`. So make sure you are using the appropriate parent theme.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am trying to set the background color dynamically in code (not via custom style).

Comment: Seeing the answers on the link that you gave, they are trying comparing the name of the view to an "internal" class `com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView`. I'm sure that it was not intended to be used directly like this. In any release the name or path 'might' change, which will probably break your app. If you come across any way to do it programatically in a clean way, please do post your answer here. Thanks. It would be good to know.

Comment: yes, this is definitely the issue, com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView, is not found on my test devices. i will try finding the source xml for the overflow menu and access the menu using the getResouces().getIdentifier() approach to set the view manually in code.

Comment: If you insist on changing the color on runtime, why not make two different `themes` in `style.xml` and programmatically switch themes. That seems lesser work than what you mentioned. And you can use xml for defining them

Comment: good question. the reason is because the theme is based on input from the user during runtime (they can pick any color to define their style/theme). ultimately, this would be the case, but currently, i don't have a solution. is there a way to set the style value at runtime?

Comment: Not sure about that, but if you've few predefined number of colors that you are want the user to choose from, you can do something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/6390025/1306419

Comment: ok, not sure i am describing my requirement. i want to be able to do this in the java code of my activity: getActionBar().getOverflowMenu().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(userDefinedColor); and since the method getOverflowMenu() does not exist, is there another way?