# Change text color of a single item in a PopupMenu

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have a popup menu that appears when the user clicks an image. The code used is:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, mImageView);
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(MyClass.this);
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_my_class_options);
popupMenu.show();
```

The menu has three actions, and I would like that the text in one of them to be colored red (instead of black).

Is that possible?
I've found some answers (*e.g.*, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591164/how-to-change-menu-item-color-size-programmatically)) that show how to do this with the activity's Options Menu, but they require access to the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method...

Thanks in advance.

-- EDIT --

The menu file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_edit"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_edit_address"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_retake_photo"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_retake_photo"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_delete"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_delete_shipment"
        android:visible="true"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Could you provide the xml of menu_my_class_options ?

Comment: Edited the message to provide the menu xml file.

Comment: did you come accross this answer then ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25731668/4706693

Comment: @NicolasSimon: Yes, but that would change the text color of all items, and I only want to change the color of one of them.
And note that I'm not using the options menu, I'm using a pop up menu (_PopupMenu_ class), and I only have access to the _onMenuItemClick()_ method, and not to any _onCreate..._ method.

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve this by following steps.

In your style.xml--- add the lines

```
<style name="style" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> 
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceColor</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/myPopupMenuStyle</item>

</style>
```

And below code

```
<style name="myPopupMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">

</style>
<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000(Your Color Code)</item>
</style>
```

**Update for single menu item color**

For single menu item color you can simply use the below code

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    int positionOfMenuItem = 0; 
// 0 or whatever your item position at which you want to change the color...
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My red MenuItem");
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED//your color), 0, s.length(), 0);
    item.setTitle(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Sadiq. Wouldn't that change the text color of all items? I only want to change the color of one of them...

Comment: @FilipeRamos yes you are right. I also added the code as per your requirment in update. Please check

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I'm not using the options menu, I'm using a pop up menu (_PopupMenu_ class), and I only have access to the _onMenuItemClick()_ method, and not to any _onCreate..._ method! :-/

Comment: Then why don't you use the custom popup. It will be easy for you

Comment: @Sadiq How can we change the textSize in a custom PopupMenu?

Answer (score 8):

I know that this answer is belated, but maybe  it will be useful for somebody. Try to use this

```
<string name="action_delete_shipment"><font fgcolor='#FF1400'>Delete Shipment</font></string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @Shadik Khan, actually you just need to create SpannableString, change the color or it before putting the item into the menu list. Like below

```
if (messageActionMap.keyAt(i) == LIST_ITEM_DELETE) {
                    SpannableString itemRecall = new SpannableString(messageActionMap.valueAt(i));
                    itemRecall.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)), 0, itemRecall.length(), 0);
                    mMessagePopupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, messageActionMap.keyAt(i), 1, itemRecall);
                }
```