# Can I change color of Android menu dynamically?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-menu

Is it possible to change color of menu (I mean background, text colors and icons) dynamically from code in Android? If so, how to do it?

I know it is possible to do so if we declare color styles first and then load. But I want to get color data from server and then set it dynamically from code without previously declaring it in Theme.

Comment: you can do it using `Html.fromHtml()` method .....

Answer (score 1):

Try this for changing background/text color:
[How to change Menu Item Color & Size programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591164/how-to-change-menu-item-color-size-programmatically)

For changing text/icon you can simply override onCreateOptionsMenu() method and save your Menu object.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
        Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_xml, menu);
    yourMenu = menu;
}
```

Then after making request to your API find menu items and change your icon/text by:

```
MenuItem menuItem = yourMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.your_drawable);
menuItem.setTitle("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a customMenu xml for this. Define all the color codes in the app with individual keys. From the server you can pass the keys and the corresponding color will be picked.

Else you can even pass the Hex color codes from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Save your color in sharedpreferance. Then always getColor from the shared preferance and set it to menu. Whenever you want to update the color, send a gcm message from server to mobile with new color code. On receive the code, update the color code in shared preferance. Menu color will be automatically changed.