# changing text size of popup menu item

Tags: android, popup, textview, menuitem

I want to change the text size of popup menu item. I have written this code to create a popup menu.
But my problem is I couldnot access the textView of popupmenu ie"EXIT" so that i could use

```
    exitItem.setTextSize(40);


    //my code
    popupmenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, findViewById(R.id.actionbar_item));
    popupmenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "Exit");
    popupmenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
```

I have not created any seperate xml file to inflate these items. I want to do it programatically as these popupitems are dynamically generated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you solve your problem?

Comment: No i am still stuck.. i am thinking of changing the whole scenario from my side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a font for the Options menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135699/how-to-set-a-font-for-the-options-menu)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not trivial. To change `MenuItem` appearance, even in this simple case, you'll have to set a custom `View` to it. But that will work only if `MenuItem` is shown as action, i.e. not in a list, which is not your case. To customise the appearance of your list in `PopupMenu` you have to use `PopUpWindow` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15454995/2093236) for example.

In your case, as you want to add elements dynamically maybe the best solution will be to implement your own `Adapter` with proper `getView()` method and use it together with `ListView` and `PopUpWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it cannot be done like that. The closest thing you can do is the following:

- Create a `View` `previousView` which implements `R.id.actionbar_item`
- Use that `View` to manipulate the text size
- Add an item to your `PopupMenu` via `popupmenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 0 , Menu.NONE, "Exit");`
- Create a `MenuItem` object `menuItem` via `MenuItem menuItem = popupmenu.getMenu().getItem(0);`
- Then set `menuItem.setActionView(previousView);`

This is your best bet, but I haven't tested it yet. Good luck!