# Set custom font for menu items in Android

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, typeface

I tried to implement a custom menu. I used the answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135699/how-to-set-a-font-for-the-options-menu) question. In my code the name is ExpandedMenuItem, but in all the examples it is IconMenuItemView. What is happening there? How can I correct this?

Here is my code.

```
    public class MyActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

         @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.proximity_alert_menu, menu);
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {         

                        //if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItem")) {}
                        try {
                           LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                           final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
                           new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                           public void run() {
                            TextView tView = (TextView) view;
                            tView.setTypeface(Config.set_font);
                            tView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                           }
                    });
                    return view;
                 } catch (InflateException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 return null;
      }
        });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
    }
```

Exception show that

```
      java.lang.ClassCastException:com.android.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

How can i cast this into TextView?

Comment: You're trying to cast apples to oranges. In order to cast `ExpandedMenuView` to `TextView` successfully, `ExpandedMenuView` must extend `TextView`, which it doesn't.

Comment: yes that is the problem. how can i make this solved? i mean get any *View* which can cast to `TextView` as a `name`? do you know the reason why i have recieved this `ExpandedMenuView` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check as follows that the `View` is `TextView` or not...

```
if (view instanceof TextView) {
    TextView tView = (TextView) view;
    tView.setTypeface(Config.set_font);
    tView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

If the view is `TextView` then the `Font` and `Color` will be changed.

Comment: it is not return as `TextView`. do you know how to make receive `TextView`?

Answer (score -4):

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(MainActivity.this.getAssets(),
            "MuseoSansCyrl.otf");
    MenuItem i = menu.findItem(R.id.item1);
    TextView itemuser = (TextView) i.getActionView();

           Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "MuseoSansCyrl.otf");
           itemuser.setTypeface(tf);
           itemuser.setText("Item1");
           itemuser.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
           retun true;
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.