# How to keep the font size of "options menu" constant , for all native size configurations?

Tags: android

I'm using the normal "options menu". When I change the Native size of my device from suppose "small" to "large" , my "options menu" also get changed with it.

I want some way in which i can keep the font size of my "options menu"static throughout the application .Regardless of my native size setting.

I've tried links like:

[How to set a font for the Options menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135699/how-to-set-a-font-for-the-options-menu/19781769#19781769)

but this way i have to insert every item. Is there some efficient way available??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use onConfigurationChanged in Application class and set the old configuration again.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

 Configuration config;
private float mDefaultFont=1.15f;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.fontScale=mDefaultFont;
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, dm);
  }
@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
  config.fontScale = mDefaultFont;
  DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  getResources().updateConfiguration(config, dm);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `sp` units in `textSize` attributes, system respects native size setting. You may use `dp` units to ignore this behavior, nevertheless it is not recommended.

For options menu you can try to override menu style (`itemTextAppearance` available since api 11):

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenuStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: I was unable to to find "textSize" attribute in menu.xml. Did you try this??

Comment: Ok, i missed that, I added an answer before your edits