# Custom font for appcompat SeachView Widget

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm facing the following problem:

I'm using a custom font for all my TextViews, Buttons, EditTexts etc.

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

The only View which hasn't the custom font is the SearchView Widget (*android.support.v7.widget.SearchView*), which is added to the menu via xml.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_message_search"
          android:title="@string/search_placeholder"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Any idea how to set a custom font to this view?

Thank you :)

Comment: Check This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135699/how-to-set-a-font-for-the-options-menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find view,

```
SearchView sv = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id. menu_item_message_search);
```

In this code, I m not sure that it will cast to SearchView although **findItem** work. Because I added menu not with xml.

After that you can find **SearchAutoComplete** from SearchView by this code

```
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) sv.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

And then, you can set Typeface for **searchAutoComplete**.

```
searchAutoComplete.setTypeface(typeface)
```

good luck, I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using appcompat 22.1.0. Looking at source code of `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` class, the text field is a static nested class `SearchAutoComplete`, [which relies on `autoCompleteTextViewStyle`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#L1639). Overriding this in your theme will allow you to change font family.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextView</item>
</style>

<style name="AutoCompleteTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    ...
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="AutoCompleteTextViewTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
</style>
```

Note that `android:fontFamily` is only available from API 16.